# Table value being set as the value of another table depending on the day of the week

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have two tables, `table1` contains "Username" and 7 more columns containing a value for each day of the week. `table2` contains three columns, "Username", "Date" and a third column which I wish to set equal to `table1`'s "day of the week" column corressponding to the dates day of the week of the inserted row. The second table is updated with a new rows for every user each day.

*[I hope that made sense!]*

Originally, I was looking at the possibility of using a computed column which called a function returning the value equal to the day of the week:

```
[dbo].[functionName]
(
    @colUsername varchar(25),
    @colDate date
)
RETURNS numeric(18, 0)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @result numeric(18, 0)


    SELECT @result = CASE DATEPART(dw, @colDate)
        WHEN 1 THEN (SELECT SUNDAY FROM dbo.table1 WHERE USERNAME = @colUsername)
        WHEN 2 THEN (SELECT MONDAY FROM dbo.table1 WHERE USERNAME = @colUsername)
        WHEN 3 THEN (SELECT TUESDAY FROM dbo.table1 WHERE USERNAME = @colUsername)
        WHEN 4 THEN (SELECT WEDNESDAY FROM dbo.table1 WHERE USERNAME = @colUsername)
        WHEN 5 THEN (SELECT THURSDAY FROM dbo.table1 WHERE USERNAME = @colUsername)
        WHEN 6 THEN (SELECT FRIDAY FROM dbo.table1 WHERE USERNAME = @colUsername)
        WHEN 7 THEN (SELECT WORKINGSATURDAY FROM dbo.table1 WHERE USERNAME = @colUsername)
    END


    RETURN @result
END
```

And was set as a computed column as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.table2 ADD
    COLNAME AS dbo.functionName(USERNAME, DATE)
GO
```

This works fine and as expected, however, since it is a computed column, when values in `table1` change, all of the values are updated in `table2` as well whereas I need the old values to remain static, and for the updated `table1` values to only be added to new rows of `table2`.

I'm looking for suggestions on how to go about achieving this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to accomplish this is probably to just use the same function you've written but call it in your insert to `table2` and have the column not be computed.

If you have a working insert with the computed column, and really can't get the insert to work with the computation being done as part of the insert, a rather hackish way of working around it might be to have an on-insert trigger on `table2` that copies the computed value to another column.  Then you'll have the changing value and a stable value in the same table.

Or have an on-insert trigger on `table2` call your function to populate the value and you should be able to get back to only one column with a stable value.

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, this is exactly what I already tried, the problem arose when I realised the function will not support a multi-row insert (which is occasionally how data will be added to `table2`). I suppose I should've said that - I'll add it to the question now

Comment: If you post the code for your attempt at inserting this way maybe someone  can help you get it to work.

Comment: Your edit would work as a last resort, I suppose - I'm looking at editing the entire question since the way which data is inserted is via a trigger (see: [StackOverflow](http://goo.gl/R0ok8)) and adding it to the end will create confusion. Thanks a lot so far though!

Comment: I was massively overcomplicating things on my attempt to do this on an insert, I've now got it working as per your first suggestion! Cheers.